# Activity Loads Twice onClick

Tags: android, android-activity

I've tried everything I've seen on this site and still no luck. I have my MainActivity which checks if the user has logged in or not. If they have it launches a fragment called ActiveThreadFragment and if they haven't it launches a login screen. The user then enters their credentials and presses sign in. It loads up a progress box and then brings up the login screen again with a Toast saying "Login Successful". What am I doing wrong? Probably really obvious but please take a look at my code.

**MainActivity**

```
if (PreferenceConnector.readString(this, "authToken") == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstLoginActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        initUI();
    }

    if (PreferenceConnector.readString(this, "authToken") != null &&
            PreferenceConnector.readString(this, "authToken").equalsIgnoreCase("skip")) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceConnector.getEditor(this);
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

**FirstLoginActivity**

```
private void initUI() {
    mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FirstLoginActivity.this,
                    "Please wait", "Checking credentials", true);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (isDataValid()) {
                            sendCredentials();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed - Invalid Username and/or " +
                                    "Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(20000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }).start();

        }
    });

    mSkipText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PreferenceConnector.writeString(getApplicationContext(), "authToken", "skip");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<activity android:name=".activity.FirstLoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode = "singleInstance">

</activity>
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: wich activity is loading twice?

Comment: @BOUTERBIATOualid the FirstLoginActivity

Comment: Do you ever set `PreferenceConnector.readString(this, "authToken")` to anything other than `null`, seems as you are going back to your other activity it is? Also `Thread.sleep(20000);` seems irrelavant, you are sleeping for 20s after the checks have been completed, but before the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: @ChrisHandy I set it in the request. I've made the sleep smaller. Just to show the user that something is going on. Still doing the same thing :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SharedPreferences` I am not quite sure where you got this `PreferenceConnector` class from but I doubt it is saving things properly.

**Reading**

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String authToken = myPrefs.getString("authToken",null);
```

**Writing**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("authToken", newToken);
editor.commit()
```